# Reload some directives after generated html code

Tags: html, angular6

I'm trying to create some html dynamically with angular framework from **ngOnInit** function. I want to add events thanks to directives on this generated html. The fact is that all directives are loaded before html generation and I didn't succeed to reload one of these.

I'm generating html in my components with **Renderer2**:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularDraggableDirective } from 'angular2-draggable';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
  })
export class TestComponent {

  @ViewChild("myDiv", {static: false}) divView: ElementRef;
  private myDiv: ElementRef;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
      this.myDiv = el;
  }

  ngOnInit(){

      let div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
      let text = this.renderer.createText('Generated draggable');

      this.renderer.setAttribute(div, 'ngdraggable', '');

      this.renderer.appendChild(div, text);
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.myDiv.nativeElement, div);
  }

}
```

And associate html is really simple:

```
<div #myDiv>
</div>
<div ngDraggable>Not generated draggable</div>
```

The first div (generated one) isn't draggable.
This second (initial one) is draggable.

Is there any way to reload my **AngularDraggableDirective** to set events on my generated div?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should write the code in `ngafterviewinit` method.